# how to get workflows history in sharepoint using c #

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I would like to know if you could bring the workflow history from a sharepoint list and display it in a visual studio application c#.

Comment: use this URL (_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow%20History')/items") in REST api.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm looking for I want to do it using c #